# Creating AWS policy which allows user to create resource with sepcific names only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a policy which should only allow the user to create resources with specific names ( ex username+reourcename), I know I have to use conditions in the policy but I am confused about how to use it in a different case

```
> "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
>         "Effect": "Allow",
>         "Action": [
>             "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
>             "iam:CreateGroup",
>             "iam:AddUserToGroup",
>             "iam:CreateRole",
>             "iam:CreateUser",
>             "iam:CreateAccessKey"
>         ],
>         "Resource": [
>             "arn:aws:iam::*:user/kkk7-techcloud",
>             "arn:aws:iam::*:role/kkk7-techcloud",
>             "arn:aws:iam::*:group/kkk7-techcloud"
>         ]
>     }
```

as per the above examples  this should only allow users to create groups or users with specific name ex - kkk7-techcloud , is this the only way ? or if someone can suggest a better approach

Comment: There is no way to write a policy for naming conventions.

Comment: Yeas that's true but I am looking for efficient use of conditions and resources so that we can come up with something similar to that  I am looking for something like if user 'Sutkus' is logged  in console he should be able to create a Group called 'Sutkus only,aything else is not allowed '